# My MacBook Pro Retina freezes after connecting third external monitor

Tags: display

After installing MacOS X El Capitan I'm unable to use my computer with three external monitors, after I plug third one independent of port ordering computer freezes, everything was working for quite a long time on Yosemite, how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem when I connect only one external display, but perhaps that's because it is a 4K display. So far, the only thing I've found to work is to restart the computer with the display already connected. This allows me to use the display, but if I disconnect and try to reconnect the display, it will freeze up again.

Comment: It wouldn't launch in my case at all... I will try to reinstall os..